# JMenuItem shows checkbox on the left, how to disable it?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jmenuitem

I'm building a drop down menu which resides in program menu bar and pops up a JPopupMenu if a JButton gets clicked. In the JPopupMenu there are multiple JMenuItems.

However, beside every JMenuItem it shows a checkbox! Which looks like this:

[image]

I don't think it should, and there is explicit JCheckBoxMenuItem for that.

Does anyone know why a check box appears in a JMenuItem and how do I disable / remove it?

The code

```
ImageIcon icon = ViewUtilities.createIcon("resource/gui/mainMenu.png", _buttonLength);
setIcon(icon);

JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("New Whiteboard");
menuItem.addActionListener(new NewWhiteboardActionListener());
getMenu().add(menuItem);

menuItem = new JMenuItem("Open...");
menuItem.addActionListener(new OpenFileActionListener());
getMenu().add(menuItem);

menuItem = new JMenuItem("Preferences...");
menuItem.addActionListener(new PreferencesActionListener());
getMenu().addSeparator();
getMenu().add(menuItem);

menuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
menuItem.addActionListener(new ExitActionListener());
getMenu().addSeparator();
getMenu().add(menuItem);
```

where `getMenu()` returns a `JPopupMenu`.

Thanks!

Cheers,
Shuo

---

**Edit:** I've fixed it. The problem is on [`Jide`](http://www.jidesoft.com) library. I've used it
for a custom LAF of TabbedPanel. And it *injects* LAF for popup menus
too as long as it's load.

So the solution is too set it to *don't* load menu styles.

```
LookAndFeelFactory.installJideExtension(
  LookAndFeelFactory.VSNET_STYLE_WITHOUT_MENU);
```

Comment: Perhaps the icon come from your look and feel ?... What is your look and feel ?

Comment: Do the check boxes work? If I _wanted_ this feature, I might put it in an `ActionListener`. Anything suspicious in the four you mention?

Comment: Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem. This would include trying the default LAF as suggested earlier.

Comment: To second earlier commenters, it looks like your LAF is using the JCheckBoxMenuItem UI for regular JMenuItem.

Comment: I've got it fixed. SSCCE does help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on [`Jide`](http://www.jidesoft.com) library. I've used it
for a custom LAF of TabbedPanel. And it *injects* LAF for popup menus
too as long as it's load.

So the solution is too set it to *don't* load menu styles.

```
LookAndFeelFactory.installJideExtension(
  LookAndFeelFactory.VSNET_STYLE_WITHOUT_MENU);
```

Answer (score 1):

@zavie Based on this [jide forum topic](http://forum.jidesoft.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=10807) the solution is, when using Jide to do the following before instatiating your menus

```
LookAndFeelFactory.installDefaultLookAndFeel();
LookAndFeelFactory.installJideExtension();
```

Furthermore, on Windows 7, the menu bar will have a slightly different background color than the menu items, the solution is to use JideMenu instead of JMenu.