# Jide oss: how to get checkbox in Jpopupmenu?

Tags: java, swing, jide

I am wondering how to get checkbox beside the jpopmenu items like in this question [JMenuItem shows checkbox on the left, how to disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656387/jmenuitem-shows-checkbox-on-the-left-how-to-disable-it-fixed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use standard Swing JCheckBoxMenuItems inside the JideMenu.